# PowerShell today's date 4-15-2020 (get-date).AddMonths(-6).month) expecting 4-15-2019, getting 10/31/2020

Tags: powershell, date, datetime

I'm using PowerShell to get the previous 6 months.  today's date 4-15-2020 using a foreach loop

```
$months = ((get-date).AddMonths(-1).month,(get-date).AddMonths(-2).month,(get-date).AddMonths(-3).month,(get-date).AddMonths(-4).month,(get-date).AddMonths(-5).month,(get-date).AddMonths(-6).month)
foreach($Month in $months){
$Year = (get-date).Year
$StartOfMonth = Get-Date -Year $Year -Month $Month -Day 1
$DaysInMonth = [DateTime]::DaysInMonth($Year, $Month)
$EndOfMonth = Get-Date -Year $Year -Month $Month -Day $DaysInMonth
$Month = $StartOfMonth.ToString("MMM/yyyy")
$StartOfMonth = $StartOfMonth.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
$EndOfMonth = $EndOfMonth.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
$StartOfMonth
$EndOfMonth
$Month
}
```

I get:

```
03/01/2020
03/31/2020
Mar/2020
02/01/2020
02/29/2020
Feb/2020
01/01/2020
01/31/2020
Jan/2020
12/01/2020
12/31/2020
Dec/2020
11/01/2020
11/30/2020
Nov/2020
10/01/2020
10/31/2020
Oct/2020
```

and expected

```
03/01/2020
03/31/2020
Mar/2020
02/01/2020
02/29/2020
Feb/2020
01/01/2020
01/31/2020
Jan/2020
12/01/2019
12/31/2019
Dec/2019
11/01/2019
11/30/2019
Nov/2019
10/01/2019
10/31/2019
Oct/2019
```

is this a bug or is something wrong with my code?

Comment: You keep setting the year based on the _current_ year - `$Year = (get-date).Year`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You keep setting the year based on the current year - `$Year = (get-date).Year`

I'd do the following instead:

```bsh
$today = Get-Date

foreach ($MonthOffset in -1..-6) {
    # Find a date in the intended month based on ([current date] + [month offset])
    # Extract year and month from that
    $MonthDate = $today.AddMonths($MonthOffset)
    $Year = $MonthDate.Year
    $Month = $MonthDate.Month

    $StartOfMonth = Get-Date -Year $Year -Month $Month -Day 1
    $DaysInMonth = [DateTime]::DaysInMonth($Year, $Month)
    $EndOfMonth = Get-Date -Year $Year -Month $Month -Day $DaysInMonth
    $Month = $StartOfMonth.ToString("MMM/yyyy")
    $StartOfMonth = $StartOfMonth.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
    $EndOfMonth = $EndOfMonth.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
    $StartOfMonth
    $EndOfMonth
    $Month
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the insight Mathias R. Jessen. I was able to use the above like this:

```
foreach ($MonthOffset in -1..-6) {
    # Find a date in the intended month based on ([current date] + [month offset])
    # Extract year and month from that
    $today = Get-Date
    $MonthDate = $today.AddMonths($MonthOffset)
    $Year = $MonthDate.Year
    $Month = $MonthDate.Month

    $StartOfMonth = Get-Date -Year $Year -Month $Month -Day 1
    $DaysInMonth = [DateTime]::DaysInMonth($Year, $Month)
    $EndOfMonth = Get-Date -Year $Year -Month $Month -Day $DaysInMonth
    $Month = $StartOfMonth.ToString("MMM/yyyy")
    $StartOfMonth = $StartOfMonth.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
    $EndOfMonth = $EndOfMonth.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
    $StartOfMonth
    $EndOfMonth
    $Month
}
```

Comment: @Phil Your change (pulling `$today = Get-Date` into the loop) is bad for two reasons: 1. Worse performance. 2. Your script will create unexpected results if you start it on the last day of a month close to midnight and the execution will stop after midnight.